# Erro na conversão de valor decimal no Insert C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um insert que recebe alguns parâmetros, mais no momento que montar a instrução sql esta dando erro de conversão:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

```c#
        //http://localhost:7630/api/AspNetWebApi/cadastrar/jogo/4512/20.01/20.10/5
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("cadastrar/jogo/{nJogo}/{valor}/{total}/{idusuario}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Cadastro(int nJogo, decimal valor, decimal total, int idusuario)
        {
            try
            {
                var tTabela = new JogoDetalheAplicacao();
                tTabela.Inseri(nJogo, valor,total,idusuario);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Cadastro realizado.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

```html
    public void Inseri(int nJogo, decimal valor, decimal total, int idusuario)
    {
        var strQuery = "";
        strQuery += "INSERT INTO TB_JOGO_DETALHE_TEMP (NUMERO_JOGO, VALOR_JOGO,VALOR_TOTAL,IDUSUARIO)";
        strQuery += string.Format(" VALUES (");
        strQuery += string.Format(" {0}, ", nJogo);
        strQuery += string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, " {0:0.00}, ", valor);
        strQuery += string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, " {0:0.00}, ", total);
        strQuery += string.Format(" {0} ", idusuario);
        strQuery += string.Format(" ) ");


        using (contexto = new Contexto())
        {
            contexto.ExecutaComando(strQuery);
        }

    }
```

Resultado da consulta sql final:

```sql
INSERT INTO TB_JOGO_DETALHE_TEMP (NUMERO_JOGO, VALOR_JOGO,VALOR_TOTAL,IDUSUARIO) VALUES ('4512','20,01','20,10','5' )
```

O correto seria vir assim:

```sql
INSERT INTO TB_JOGO_DETALHE_TEMP (NUMERO_JOGO, VALOR_JOGO,VALOR_TOTAL,IDUSUARIO) VALUES ('4512',20.01,20.10,'5' )
```

Comment: Testei aqui e a consulta ficou como esperado, da uma olhada : https://dotnetfiddle.net/0On7LU

Comment: @JoelRamosMichaliszen, no seu exemplo da certo, mais no meu já fiz vários tipos de conversão é não deu certo

Comment: Quais são os tipos dos campos??: **(NUMERO_JOGO, VALOR_JOGO,VALOR_TOTAL,IDUSUARIO)**

Comment: @JoelRamosMichaliszen, 
int nJogo, decimal valor, decimal total, int idusuario

Comment: Sim, mas tipo do campo no banco, ex: decima(10,2)

Comment: numeric(8, 2) para os valores, o restante é int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como os campos são inteiros e numeric(8,2), não é preciso das aspas, Tenta este *format*:

```
strQuery += string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture," VALUES ({0},{1:0.00},{2:0.00},{3})", nJogo, valor, total, idusuario);
```

Comment: o resultado final: INSERT INTO TB_JOGO_DETALHE_TEMP (NUMERO_JOGO, VALOR_JOGO,VALOR_TOTAL,IDUSUARIO) VALUES ('4512',20,01,20,10,'5' ), ainda da erro, por causa da virgula

Comment: @itasouza editei a resposta e tira as aspas dos int's tambem

Comment: @itasouza Testou o format que coloquei na minha resposta?

Comment: sim, eu fiz o seu exemplo mais não deu certo, eu postei na pergunta como ficou o código

Comment: @itasouza Esse format ````strQuery += string.Format(" VALUES ({0},{1:0.00},{2:0.00},{3})", nJogo, valor, total, idusuario);````?

Comment: eu conseguir resolver: 
strQuery += string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, " {0:0.00}, ", valor);

Comment: é preciso adicionar o CultureInfo.InvariantCulture em cada linha

Comment: @itasouza  Veja minha resposta agora, e marque como correta xD

Comment: faz assim, pega o código correto, adiciona na sua pergunta é ai eu marco como resposta, o código esta na minha pergunta.

Comment: @itasouza usa o meu código, tem menos linha e é mais performático.

Answer (score 2):

O seu problema é que o `string.Format` usa as informações da cultura atual para decidir como converter um número para string.

Isso geralmente não é um problema para números inteiros, porém para números com casas decimais ele é bem problemático, pois em um SO em português ele vai usar a vírgula como separador decimal, enquanto que em inglês ele vai usar o ponto.

Se tratando de montar uma SQL isso se torna um problema maior, já que em uma SQL você precisa sempre usar ponto como separador decimal, felizmente isso é bem simples de resolver já que o `string.Format` aceita um `IFormatProvider` como primeiro parâmetro, o qual ele vai usar para definir como efetuar a conversão, e convenientemente o `CultureInfo` implementa esta interface, então você pode forçar ele a usar um `CultureInfo` específico, no caso podendo ser o `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` que sempre formata números com ponto como separador decimal.

```
strQuery += string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, " VALUES ({0},{1},{2},{3})", nJogo, valor, total, idusuario);
```

E como todos os seus valores são numéricos então não se deve usar as aspas na SQL.

Agora apenas como observação, a forma como você está fazendo é praticamente o mesmo que concatenar valores em uma SQL, o que não é recomendado, o ideal é sempre utilizar parâmetros em qualquer consulta SQL, e o uso deles também evitaria esse erro já que você poderia passar os valores já no tipo correto para o banco de dados, sem precisar converter para string.

Comment: eu alterei a minha pergunta com o código ajustado com a sua resposta, mesmo assim eu recebo os valores com virgula